# How to create a PDF file from HTML using PDFBox?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I am trying to create a PDF from HTML content.

```
public byte[] generatePdf(final XhtmlPDFGenerationRequest request) {

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
    InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(request.getContent()
            .getBytes());

    PDStream pdstream = new PDStream(document, stream);
    document.save(baos);
    document.close();
    return this.toByteArray(baos);

}
```

When I take this `byte[]` and save to a file, the file is blank. I am using `PDStream` to embed the input stream into the document

From the http://pdfbox.apache.org/apidocs/

```
public PDStream(PDDocument doc,
                InputStream str)
         throws IOException
```

Reads all data from the input stream and embeds it into the document, this will close the `InputStream`.

Comment: I was looking for an HTML to PDF renderer. We were using iText. I was looking to do same with Apache PDFBox. But, it looks like it cannot be done. I can either use [Apache FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/) or continue using iText. Here is the iText solution if anyone is interested:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14359810/java-render-xml-document-as-pdf/19792259#19792259 If you are looking for a solution for merging using PDF box, here it is [Merge pdf files using Apache pdf box](http://www.skill-guru.com/blog/2013/11/05/merging-pdf-using-apache-pdfbox/)

Answer (score 9):

[Open HTML to PDF library](https://github.com/danfickle/openhtmltopdf) uses PDFBox under the hood and hides all the conversion complexity.

Usage is quite simple:

```
try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("/Users/me/output.pdf")) {
    PdfRendererBuilder builder = new PdfRendererBuilder();
    builder.withUri("file:////Users/me/input.html");
    builder.toStream(os);
    builder.run();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add / warn for anyone else finding this in 2023 that openhtmltopdf currently has the mantainer uncontactable, though some seem like they may be mantaining a fork (see [this issue](https://github.com/danfickle/openhtmltopdf/issues/921)!), while flying saucer isn't mantained either (see [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/g/flying-saucer-users/c/LJQOzkaHC7Y)! and [this one](https://groups.google.com/g/flying-saucer-users/c/ySI8HrLI70A)! on the google group).