# How to print html text in pdf using apache pdfbox

Tags: java, html, pdfbox

I want to print html text in my pdf how to print it.
Ex: if my text is <b > Hai </b > then while printing pdf it should be bold like **Hai** rather than printing the complete html string as it is

Comment: related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19713479/how-to-create-a-pdf-file-from-html-using-pdfbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not available in PDFBox. Use a tool on top of PDFBox like [openhtmltopdf](https://github.com/danfickle/openhtmltopdf).

Comment: yes i tried with openhtmltopdf. it worked.i have one more question is there any way to append that text to existing page in the pdf. because now after converting the html we are merging that document to the existing pdf. I want to merge html contents to an existing page

Comment: Yes, either use the PDFMerger command line application (part of pdfbox-app*.jar), or use the `PDFMergerUtility` class.