# Can't see images on pdf generated from html

Tags: java, html, pdf, pdfbox, openhtmltopdf

I'm using ApachePDFBox to generate a pdf from an html file.

The point is that I can't see the images on the pdf.

Here is my resources folder:

[image]

And here is the html code:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
        <img src="../img/logo.png" width="30%"/>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I see the logo properly on the html, but I don't see the image on the pdf.

To generate the pdf I'm using this example right here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64777489/6418839

Thank you very much
Best regards!

Comment: Hi K J, thank you very much for your response :)
I do not see the image neither in the pdf nor in the html

Comment: Note: the `<img>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: Hi Rob, thank you for your comment. I have anothers html with the same img tag and all of them work correctly, also the pdf if I use itext instead of pdfbox

Comment: Are you using the latest openhtmltopdf and does this use the latest PDFBox (2.0.24)? I remember that there was a problem in PDFBox that certain images (16 bit png) weren't properly handled.

Answer (score 1):

This has helped in my case, I had to use an absolute file path as posted here: https://github.com/danfickle/openhtmltopdf/issues/620#issuecomment-747380503

```
<img src="file:///D:/repos/local-projects/ExportExperiments/smiley.png" alt="Smiley"/>
```